# VS2012 pubxml and TransformWebConfigEnabled

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publishing

Maybe someone can advise me.

I am trying to publish a project using VS2012. I have setup a publish profile to publish it to  a file system drive.

I have several environments/build configurations required and thusly am using Web.Config transformations.

At the moment, I have a web.config + 5 transforms (one for each build config). When the solution is published, it successfully deploys to the file system specified. However it also transforms the Web.Config into web.config.

I have modified the .pubxml to include the `<TransformWebConfigEnabled>False</TransformWebConfigEnabled>` element, but the publish process just seems to ignore it and transform the web.config regardless.
Followed via this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465342(v=vs.100).aspx

Can anyone advise?

[edit]
I have tried putting `<TransformWebConfigEnabled>False</TransformWebConfigEnabled>` element into both the pubxml and the proj file and both ways it get's completely ignored and the web.config is transformed regardless.

Answer (score 2):

You are sticking it in the wrong file. You want to modify

> `YourProject.csproj`

instead of `PublishProfile.pubxml`.